# How to get all the combination in order

Tags: algorithm

For example

```
Input

2,1,3

Output

1,1,1
1,1,2
1,1,3
2,1,1
2,1,2
2,1,3
```

Comment: The output doesn't make sense. It's certainly not permutations of the input. If you allow duplicates and using only part of the input sequence, it's incomplete (for example, missing 333). Does the order matter? Is 213 the same as 312? Do you have a language of choice?

Comment: The out put should in order. The output is full.

Comment: @bruce - do you mean that the output should be full (even though it isn't in your example)?

Comment: @Ted Hopp I mean there is not any output not written.

Comment: @TrueWill: I think the problem is asking for all combinations made with 2 or 1 in the first spot, 1 in the second, and 3, 2,or 1 in the third.  So less than or equal the number given. @bruce is this correct?  Do you have a language/style you need the answer in (very different functional and imperative solutions)?

Comment: @Philip JF Correct! Such as php/c/java all are ok.

Comment: @Fantius The input is an example, it also can be 3,4,9,2... etc

Comment: I get it now.  The input items are not being rearranged at all.

Comment: @Philip - Nice job deciphering the specifications. I missed that!

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understand the question then this should work (code is in Haskell, will produce the results in a different order than the example)

```
combinations [] = []
combinations [x]
    |x > 0 = [x]:combinations [(x-1)]
    |otherwise = []
combinations (x:xs)
    |x > 0 = (map (\c -> x:c) (combinations xs)) ++ combinations((x-1):xs)
    |otherwise = []
```

Or this to get it in the same order as you gave (also just a nicer solution)

```
 combinations' [x] = [[c]|c<-[1..x]]
 combinations' (x:xs) = [c:d|c<-[1..x],d<-combinations' xs]
```

It will take me a bit to produce an answer in an "imperative" language (C, Java, etc).  This is the kind of thing where functional languages shine.

---

Okay, so in Java.
Disclaimer: this code is more or less just a direct translation of the Haskell.  It isn't clean, or the best way of doing things.  I have not tested it, or really given it enough thought to make sure it is correct

```
public List<List<Integer>> combinations(List<Integer> workwith){
    List<List<Integer>> d = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
    if(workwith.size() == 1){
            int max = workwith.get(0);
        for(int i = 1; i=<max;i++){
            List<Integer> toAdd = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            toAdd.add(i);
            d.add(toAdd);
        }
        return d
    }
    Integer max = workwith.remove(0);
    List<List<Integer>> back = combinations(workwith);
    for(int i = 1, i<=max;i++)
        for(List<Integer> b: back){
        List<Integer> toAdd = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            toAdd.add(i);
            toAdd.addAll(b);
            d.add(toAdd)
        }
    }
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a[] - is an input vector

```
int prod = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) prod *= a[i];  // find the count of lines in output

for (int i = 0; i < prod; i++){
     vector<int> b;                         // vector of the current output
     for (int j = a.size()-1; j >= 0; j--){ // for each output calculate its values
          b[j] = i % a[j];                  // each value will be between 0 and a[j]  
          i /= a[j];
     }
     for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++)     // output it
          cout << b[j] + 1 << " ";
     cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient way to do it, but here's a C implementation:

```
/* Assumes output is allocated with enough room for 'len' ints. */
/* Generates the 'num'-th combination in 'output'. */
void get_comb_number(int num, int len, int *input, int *output) {
    int i;
    for (i=num-i-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        output[i] = (num % input[i]) + 1;
        num /= input[i];
    }
}
```

Then you can just loop from 0 to the product of the input (for the example above it would be `2*1*3 = 6`), calling `get_comb_number` for each and print out each combination. The code is slightly inefficient because it has to call a function for each combination and has to do all the mods and divisions for each combination, but IMO the simplicity of the code makes up for it if you don't need the efficiency. Note that the combination number will overflow somewhat quickly, but assuming 32-bit ints, you'll be spending several minutes just generating all the combinations at that point and much much longer trying to print them all.